# Javascript parasitic inheritance, closures

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, closures

I'm trying to understand JavaScript parasitic behaviour in the closures.

Can someone tell me why we need to return a self variable inside the `Teacher` function constructor?

```
 function Person(name, age) {
  return {
    getName: function() {
      return name;
    },
    getAge: function() {
      return age;
   },
 };
}

function Teacher(name, age, subject) {
  let self = Person(name, age);
  self.teach = function() {
    return `${name} is teaching ${subject}.`;
  };
  return self;
}
```

Comment: This is a strange pattern: these constructors do no create instances of `Person` nor `Teacher`.

Comment: https://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Comment: If you'd omit the `return self` and then call the Teacher function with `new` you would get an actual Teacher Instance. In your case you just return an augmented object produced by the Person function.

Comment: The closure in Teacher is of name, age and subject, but not of self.  self is simply a local variable that has a reference to the person object you create.  If you want to use the object later, it has to be returned.

Comment: @subarachnid This is not that type of pattern.  It is a simpler form of objects.  No `new` needed but `instanceof` can't be used.

Comment: I am aware of that. It just wanted to illustrate why returning `self` is neccessary. Obviously the function would otherwise return `undefined` when it is called without `new`.

Answer (score 2):

In the parasitic pattern you have chosen, a `return` is necessary as otherwise executing `new Teacher` would return a rather empty instance of `Teacher` (i.e. `this`). With this pattern you choose to avoid using `this`, which is actually the object that JavaScript prepares for you when you use `new`.

If you choose to use the parasitic inheritance pattern in JavaScript, it comes down to ignoring `new` and avoiding `this`, and explicitly creating a parent object (called `self` here), extending it, and returning it.

Note that you can perform all three steps in "one" go, with the use of `Object.assign`, which allows you to use a similar object literal syntax as you have in `Person`:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  return {
    getName: function() {
      return name;
    },
    getAge: function() {
      return age;
   },
 };
}

function Teacher(name, age, subject) {
  return Object.assign(Person(name, age), {
    teach() {
      return `${name} is teaching ${subject}.`;
    }
  });
}
```

The downside of this pattern is that each time you construct an object, new function objects are created for `getAge`, `getName` and `teach`. This is a pity. Prototypal inheritance offers methods which only exist once and can be called on different object instances (with the `this`-binding facility). On top of that, it allows you to check the "type" of an object using `instanceof`.

Although opinions will differ on which patterns are better than others, it is clear that with parasitic inheritance you are fighting against the standard, prototypal inheritance pattern, which also got a revamp with the introduction of the `class` syntax.